# Calculating axis angle from matrix without wrapping at PI

Tags: matrices

I need to get the axis angle from a matrix of the form:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & tx\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & ty\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}
$$

Into an axis angle. I've tried the standard formula:

$\theta$ = $\arccos$ ( (m[0][0] + m[1][1] + m[2][2] - 1) / 2 )

However this formula inverts when the angle reaches PI. For example, given a rotational matrix for an angle of 225 degrees, we get a returned value of about 135 degrees, which in itself is perfectly correct, but I really need the full value.

Is there any way of handling these cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an [Atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function available, which sorts out the quadrants.  If so, you want Atan2$(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$  Otherwise, you can do $\arccos\theta$ but then you have to sort out the quadrants afterward using the value for $\sin\theta$

Comment: So the angle would be atan2(m[0][0],m[1][0])?

Comment: Thanks for the help Ross, I ended up using the arccos approach and made it adjust the quadrant when sin theta is negative. Works fine now!